# unable to use custom commands in cypress with type script

Tags: cypress

we are using typescript to write our tests following is my code e.g. "mytest.spec.ts"`

```
beforeEach(() => cy.visit('/'));

it('search for a valid policy', () => {
 cy.get('#searchbox').type('1111')
 cy.login('test username','test password')
})
```

in my command.ts

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {console.log('Custom command example: Login', email, password);});
```

I have also tried from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Types-for-custom-commands

but no luck. it doesn't work

Comment: Can you define 'doesn't work' in your question.

Comment: it cannot access that custom command.nothing is printed in the log

Comment: Can you check with `cy.log()` instead of `console.log` as cy commands are asynchronous.

Comment: The problem is not logging. that login method that I have written command.ts when I call from spec file, it is not even calling that method

Comment: Is it imported in `index/support` ?